# Dynamically add wrapper element in vue3 composition api

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-functional-component

Consider a component below, which accepts `tag` as props.

```
<template>
    <input v-model="model"/>
</template>
<script>
export default { 
    name: "InputComponent",
    props: {
        tag: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: null,
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I want passing the props `div` as `tag` value should return dom below.

```
<div>
   <input v-model="model"/>
</div>
```

> Solution with composition api is advantange.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
    <component :is="tag">
        <input v-model="model"/>
    </component>
</template>
<script>
    export default { 
        name: "InputComponent",
        props: {
            tag: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
                default: null,
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: what about no tag conditions ?

Comment: You can work with `v-if` and `v-else` or pass a render function as prop (tag), to render the wrapper